# How to convert this CSV into Json?

Tags: python, json, pandas

How to convert this CSV into custom JSON format , (I have attached my code research below, unable to get the required output structure)
I have csv in pandas dataframe

Converting this csv into json

[image]

**Expected out from the csv to json**

```
[
    {
        "name": "your_name",
        "email": "your_email"
    },
    [
        [
            {
                "col1": "Phoebe",
                "col2": "Oh my God, he\u0092s lost it. He\u0092s totally lost it.",
                "col3": "PREDICTED_EMOTION"
            },
            {
                "col1": "Monica",
                "col2": "What?",
                "col3": "PREDICTED_EMOTION"
            },

        .....
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Given:

```
$ cat x.csv 
col1    col2    col3
0.123   this is a text  txt
0.987   whatever this is    spam
0.429   yummy, frites   fries
```

For columns as json key:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('x.csv', sep='\t')
>>> df
    col1              col2   col3
0  0.123    this is a text    txt
1  0.987  whatever this is   spam
2  0.429     yummy, frites  fries
>>> df.to_json()
'{"col1":{"0":0.123,"1":0.987,"2":0.429},"col2":{"0":"this is a text","1":"whatever this is","2":"yummy, frites"},"col3":{"0":"txt","1":"spam","2":"fries"}}'
```

For rows as json keys:

```
>>> df.T
                   0                 1              2
col1           0.123             0.987          0.429
col2  this is a text  whatever this is  yummy, frites
col3             txt              spam          fries
>>> df.T.to_json()
'{"0":{"col1":0.123,"col2":"this is a text","col3":"txt"},"1":{"col1":0.987,"col2":"whatever this is","col3":"spam"},"2":{"col1":0.429,"col2":"yummy, frites","col3":"fries"}}'
```

---

## Edited (not advisable for anyone to use it)

The desired json is a poorly structured json. The one that pandas give be default above is more reasonable.

If you really want the output as per the OP, then:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import json
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.read_csv('x.csv', sep='\t')
>>> tmp_json = df.T.to_json()

>>> tmp_json
'{"0":{"col1":0.123,"col2":"this is a text","col3":"txt"},"1":{"col1":0.987,"col2":"whatever this is","col3":"spam"},"2":{"col1":0.429,"col2":"yummy, frites","col3":"fries"}}'

>>> [v for k,v in eval(tmp_json).items()]
[{'col1': 0.123, 'col2': 'this is a text', 'col3': 'txt'}, {'col1': 0.987, 'col2': 'whatever this is', 'col3': 'spam'}, {'col1': 0.429, 'col2': 'yummy, frites', 'col3': 'fries'}]

>>> json.dumps([{"name": "your_name", "email": "your_email"}, tmp_json_dict])
'[{"name": "your_name", "email": "your_email"}, [{"col1": 0.123, "col2": "this is a text", "col3": "txt"}, {"col1": 0.987, "col2": "whatever this is", "col3": "spam"}, {"col1": 0.429, "col2": "yummy, frites", "col3": "fries"}]]'

>>> op_desired_json = json.dumps([{"name": "your_name", "email": "your_email"}, tmp_json_dict])

>>> pprint(eval(op_desired_json))
[{'email': 'your_email', 'name': 'your_name'},
 [{'col1': 0.123, 'col2': 'this is a text', 'col3': 'txt'},
  {'col1': 0.987, 'col2': 'whatever this is', 'col3': 'spam'},
  {'col1': 0.429, 'col2': 'yummy, frites', 'col3': 'fries'}]]
```

Comment: Hi @alvas, I want to convert the csv pandas data frame into above mentioned json format.

Comment: Where does name and email come from? They're arbitrary, unless they're in the CSV, they can't be read.

Comment: And what you provided isn't a poorly structured json. What the pandas exports (for rows as json keys) is more reasonable, At least it can query the order of the rows as a set/dictionary instead of a sequential list.

Comment: Yes, so where do they come from?

Comment: this is submission output  file so i need to add my email id and name in the json when am submitting this json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193548/discussion-between-rvknlp-and-alvas).

Comment: Nope, that's the final answer I'm going to give ;P Anything else is not going to help anyone else in the community, so the rest is up to you. I believe you can figure out the correct munging!